# How can I train a neural network with weights constrained to specific values?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a network with weights that can only have certain values. However, the way that I am doing this takes a very long time, e.g. 5h per epoch for a 3-layered fully connected network on MNIST. Is there a faster way to do this?

I am using tf.keras for building my network. I added a custom tf.constraint that does a binary search on the list of possible weight values when updating the weights. I found a binary search code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884453/binary-search-and-interpolation-in-tensorflow) that I adapted for my application. In order to apply the binary search function to all the parameters, I use "tf.map_fn".

Here is the Constraint class:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.constraints import Constraint
import tensorflow as tf

# binary search function
def find(weights, query, shape):
    vals = tf.map_fn(lambda x: weights[tf.argmin(tf.cast(x >= weights, dtype=tf.int32)[1:] - tf.cast(x >= weights, dtype=tf.int32)[:-1])], tf.reshape(query,[-1]))
    return tf.reshape(vals, shape)

class WeightQuantizeClip(Constraint):
    # weights parameter holds the possible weight values
    def __init__(self, weights = []):

        self.weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(weights)

    def __call__(self, p):
        p = find(self.weights, p, p.shape)
        return p

    def get_config(self):
        return {'name': self.__class__.__name__}
```

When I train a network with the above constraint the weights are only from the possible weight values, but the training time increases extremely. Without the binary search function, my GPU is fully utilized, but when I train with the binary search function the utilization drops to 2%. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems, that some part of the clipping op gets executed on CPU which requires RAM-VRAM communication which is *extremely* slow.

However, if you are trying to do the traditional NN quantization, there is actually a whole TF module built for this purpose, you may want to check it out, maybe it covers your use case.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/quantization/quantize

Comment: The TF quantization module does not support a lookup table sort of quantization, where each weight can have specific values. I am trying to simulate training with Analog Resistive Crossbar Arrays. That's why I need the weights to have specific values.